# Import sheets from different workbooks does not work due to sheet name?

Tags: vba, excel

Code works fine as it imports data from sheets of different workbooks with name Trippings_15.

But i want the program to import sheets with name `Trippings_Jan_15, Trippings_Feb_15, Trippings_March_15, etc` from `workbook 1,2,3` respectively when i use `Trippings_15` in code or I can simply give the absolute address of that sheet irrespective of tab name like sheet7 from all workbooks.

I am making a database where all monthly trippings of 2015 will be shown a single sheet.

```
 Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

    Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String
    FolderPath = "D:\Copy Multiple Excel to One master\"
    Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, eRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Filename = Dir(Filepath)
    Do While Filename <> ""
        eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
        On Error Goto NextFile 
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Trippings_15")
        With ws
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
            Sheet1.Cells(eRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
NextFile:
        On Error Goto 0
        wb.Close False
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why can't you use `wb.Worksheets("Trippings_Jan_15")` (and Feb, etc)?

Comment: Ugh, .Copy and .Paste is incredibly messy. Have you considered using the  `Worksheet.Copy` method? It can move worksheets between files even... And it doesn't use the clipboard. EDIT: I apologize - I missed the fact that you're concatenating to one sheet. You should not have to resort to copy/paste, though.

Comment: Still an unclear question, **PLEASE READ** http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You also have **13 questions with only 5 answers accepted**...

Comment: @agold because it will import only data of Trippings_Jan_15 not of other monthly trippings i hope i have cleared my point, i am making a database where all monthly trippings of 2015 import to a single sheet.

Comment: @R3uk edited the ques

Comment: ...What an edit... You could maybe skip some lines to make some air in your text, even use `**` or `*` to make some text as **bold** or *italic*. So I keep repeting but plz read : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and please try to **be more specific and clear in your questions, we are not here to guess what you are trying to do!**

Comment: ok boss i will try thanks alot for ur guidance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  The logic here is that you predefine the months which you will insert in the `"Trippings_15"` string.  Also, add a function to test whether sheet exists, instead of using the clunky `On Error Resume Next`

```
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

    Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

    '### DEFINE YOUR BASE STRING TO BE UPDATED WITH EACH MONTH
    Dim baseSheetName$
    baseSheetName = "Trippings_{}_15"
    Dim sheetName as String  'This will be updated later...

    '### DEFINE AN ARRAY OF MONTHS 
    Dim months, m
    months = Array("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC")

    FolderPath = "D:\Copy Multiple Excel to One master\"
    Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, eRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Filename = Dir(Filepath)
    Do While Filename <> ""
        eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)

        For Each m in months  '## Iterate over each month in your array
            sheetName = Replace(baseSheetName,"{}",m)  '## this is the month sheet name like "Trippings_Jan_15", etc.
            If SheetExists(wb, sheetName) Then   '## Check whether this sheet exists before tryingto use it
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
                With ws
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
                    Sheet1.Cells(eRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
            End If
        Next m
        wb.Close False
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Here is the function `SheetExists`:

```
Function SheetExists(wb as Workbook, s as String)
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim ret as Boolean
    For Each ws in wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = s Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    SheetExists = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Atlast someone understood my ques thanks alot for that, got syntax error at line     For m in months  '## Iterate over each month in your array   ,             For ws in wb.Worksheets        in excel

Comment: For m in months '## Iterate over each month in your array

Comment: Ahhh crud. OK, I'm doing more python code lately, cahnge it to `For each ws in ...`

Comment: For ws in wb.Worksheets

Comment: `For each ws...` and also `For each m in months` I made the revision to the answer above.

Comment: Cheers, though you should consider marking this answer as "Accepted", as the standard way of saying "thanks" on StackOverflow is to accept or upvote answers which have been helpful to solve your problem.